# What's causing spawning of Python prompt?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, anaconda, miniconda

When I try to run a python app, it opens a window with a prompt instead. Same in Visual Studio Code. I'm Using Python 3.x via Miniconda on Windows 7

Comment: It opens several prompts when I start vscode. It seems it's opening vpython

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by file infector malware, replacing executable files